# How to render a FontAwesome icon from a json file into a React Application?

Tags: html, json, reactjs, parsing, icons

Good evening,
I have the following JSON structure:

```
"Flow": [
    {
        "title": "Is your multicloud secure and scalable?",
        "icon": "<FontAwesomeIcon className='my-icon' icon={faShieldCheck} />"
    }
],
```

As you can see, it uses the React version of FontAwesome Pro. But I need to render this dynamically into a Component.

So far I've tried with different approaches. For example:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: item.icon } }></div>
```

Also tried this:

```
<div> { ReactHtmlParser(item.icon) }  </div>
```

But no luck so far.

I would appreciate any new ideas on this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over that JSON structure? Can you instead just keep the name of the icon rather than a the full component string?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I've also tried that, but with the React Fontawesome Icons you usually have to import those icons to your component. The problem here is that if I'm only consuming the name of the icon it won't render. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `quotes` in your json for `icon`.

In fact, just provide the name of the icon in the json and use `require` to import the `icon` while rendering `FontAwesomeIcon`.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fontawesome-icon-from-json-o712z?file=/src/App.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const myJson = {
  Flow: [
    {
      title: "Is your multicloud secure and scalable?",
      icon: "faHighlighter"
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        className="my-icon"
        icon={require("@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons")[myJson.Flow[0].icon]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Note** - below is cleaner code but it imports all icons before hand.

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
const icons = require("@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons");
const myJson = {
  Flow: [
    {
      title: "Is your multicloud secure and scalable?",
      icon: "faHighlighter"
    }
  ]
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <FontAwesomeIcon className="my-icon" icon={icons[myJson.Flow[0].icon]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this isn't working. The json's being consumed from the public folder. I'm working with the i18next multilanguage for React.